# Bootstrap-Tour not showing the POP-UP and the content

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tour

On click of next Button it takes to xyz.html page but neither pop-up nor the content in the jquery for the xyz.html page shows up. Any one knows why?

jQuery code:

```
    var tour = new Tour({
    storage : false,
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#ture-one",
    title: "<div class='ture-number'>1</div><div class='ture-slide-box'><div class='ture-slide-number active'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div></div>",
    placement: "bottom",
    content: "<p>This is the Deployment Manager Dashboard.</p><p>It shows you which versions of your software are deployed to your different environments.</p>"
  },
  {
    path: "xyz.html",
    element: "#ture-two",
     title: "<div class='ture-number'>2</div><div class='ture-slide-box'><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number active'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div><div class='ture-slide-number'></div></div>",
    placement: "bottom",
    content: "<p>This is the Deployment Manager Dashboard.</p><p>It shows you which versions of your software are deployed to your different environments.</p>"
  }
]});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
```

HTML code on xyz.html page:

```
<div class="project-info-box">
    <h1>Project 1</h1>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" id="ture-five" type="button">Deploy to</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out nothing was wrong with the code, it's just that i was testing it in my local and not on live server. This is what causing the pop-up and content not to appear on "xyz.html". That was stupid of me.